# Has to join std::thread in std::vector<std::thread> twice to avoid termination from thread dtor

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++17, pthread-join

I wrote a parallel program to find the Two Sum problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <future>

using std::vector;
class Solution
{
private:
    using val_t = std::pair<int, int>;
    using Container = vector<val_t>;
    using It = typename Container::iterator;
    using size_t = typename Container::size_type;

    static bool cmp(const val_t &x, const val_t &y) noexcept
    {
        return x.first < y.first;
    }

    // Precondition: data.size() == 0, nums.size() != 0
    static void make_data(Container &data, const vector<int> &nums)
    {
        data.reserve(nums.size());

        int i = 0;
        for (auto &each: nums)
            data.emplace_back(each, i++);

        std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), &cmp);
    }

    // launch_threads will launch threads in parallel.
    // It will call F with an int(thread id for accessing data) and std::forward<Args>(args)...
    template <class F>
    static void launch_threads(std::reference_wrapper<vector<std::thread>> pool, int thread_cnt, F &&f)
    {
        auto launch_other_threads = [=, f = std::forward<F>(f)]()
        {
            // This is thread 0!
            for (int i = 1; i != thread_cnt; ++i)
                pool.get().emplace_back(f, i);

            return std::invoke(f, 0);
        };

        pool.get().reserve(thread_cnt);
        pool.get().emplace_back(launch_other_threads);
    }

    // number of threads this process will ever have(including the main thread)
    int total_threads;
    // Thread pool and how much data each will process
    vector<std::thread> pool;
    size_t n;

    // The data for processing
    int target;
    Container data;
    // is_ready indicates whether the data is ready
    std::shared_future<void> is_ready;

    // Where result will be put. 
    // Since there is only one result, no atomic variable is needed
    vector<int> ret;
    // Synchronization of the event to terminate other running threads
    std::atomic_bool finished;

    void findtwoSum_impl(int thread_id, It beg, It end) noexcept
    {
        for (; beg != end && !finished.load(std::memory_order_acquire); ++beg) {
            int val = target - beg->first;
            auto it = std::lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), val_t{val, 0}, &cmp);

            if (it != data.end() && it->first == val &&
                (it->second != beg->second || (++it)->first == val)) {

                finished.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
                ret = {beg->second, it->second};
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void findtwoSum(int thread_id) noexcept
    {
        std::shared_future<void>{is_ready}.wait();

        // Calculate the data that this thread will process
        auto beg = data.begin() + n * thread_id;
        auto end = beg + n;

        return findtwoSum_impl(thread_id, beg, end);
    }

    // thread_cnt must > 0
    void launch_threads_and_prepare_data(const vector<int> &nums, int thread_cnt)
    {
        // Initial the notification mechanism
        std::promise<void> promise;
        is_ready = promise.get_future().share();

        // Launch threads
        launch_threads(pool, thread_cnt, [this](int id) noexcept {
            return findtwoSum(id);
        });

        // Prepare data
        make_data(data, nums);

        n = data.size() / total_threads;

        // Notify threads that the data is ready
        promise.set_value();
    }

    // do_last_thread_cleanup process the remaining data and join threads
    void do_last_thread_cleanup()
    {
        // The main thred is the last thread.
        int thread_id = total_threads - 1;

        // findtwoSum_impl returns if any thread find the result.
        findtwoSum_impl(thread_id, data.begin() + n * thread_id, data.end());

        // The original join loop
        // Wait for other threads to finish.
        for (auto &thread: pool)
            thread.join();

        // Clear containers
        pool.clear();
        data.clear();
    }

public:
    vector<int> twoSum(const vector<int> &nums, int target)
    {
        // Initialize class variables
        // I know that total_threads should be much lower depending on the size of input
        total_threads = 8;

        this->target = target;
        ret.reserve(2);
        finished.store(false, std::memory_order_release);

        // Initialize class variable pool, n, data and is_ready
        launch_threads_and_prepare_data(nums, total_threads - 1);

        do_last_thread_cleanup();

        return std::move(ret);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Solution s;
    s.twoSum({3, 2, 4}, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with `clang++-8 -std=c++17 -O1 -g -fsanitizer=address -lpthread -o debug.out` and when I ran `./debug.out`, it was terminated without exception.

I tried to debug it by adding `std::cerr << "!@@@" << std::endl;` after I `join()` the `std::thread`s in `std::vector<std::thread>` and before `Solution s` goes out of scope; It was shown that `pool.clear()` was the code that causes this.

I was completely confused since I have done the `join`ing right before I call `pool.clear()`. In order to find the problem, I modify the code for original `join()` to the code below:

```cpp
// The first loop
for (auto &thread: pool) {
    thread.join();
    std::cerr << " 1" << thread.get_id() << " is joinable? " << thread.joinable() << std::endl;
}

// The second loop
for (auto &thread: pool)
    if (thread.joinable())
        thread.join();
// The third loop
for (auto &thread: pool)
    std::cerr << thread.get_id() << " is joinable? " << thread.joinable() << std::endl;
```

And, again, to my surprise, I found the first loop to `join` the threads does not work at all:

```
 1thread::id of a non-executing thread is joinable? 0
thread::id of a non-executing thread is joinable? 0
thread::id of a non-executing thread is joinable? 0
thread::id of a non-executing thread is joinable? 0
thread::id of a non-executing thread is joinable? 0
thread::id of a non-executing thread is joinable? 0
thread::id of a non-executing thread is joinable? 0
thread::id of a non-executing thread is joinable? 0
```

I thought there were something wrong with the first loop I written, so I commented out and ran it again:

```
thread::id of a non-executing thread is joinable? 0
140634635626240 is joinable? 1
140634627233536 is joinable? 1
140634618840832 is joinable? 1
140634610448128 is joinable? 1
140634602055424 is joinable? 1
140634593662720 is joinable? 1
terminate called without an active exception
```

I am completely confused and have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Are you able to write a program that starts threads and collects info from them? If so, minimize what you just did above and build upon that.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea. I'll do it.

Comment: "thread::id of a non-executing thread"... maybe by the time you're joining the threads didn't started yet?

Comment: there are simpler ways to write this code. Please go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ once you have fixed your bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your bug**

Your threads are starting with `n = 0` because `data.size()` is smaller than `total_threads` and integer division `n = data.size() / total_threads;` will give zero.

```
void findtwoSum(int thread_id) noexcept
{
    std::shared_future<void>{is_ready}.wait();

    // Calculate the data that this thread will process
    auto beg = data.begin() + n * thread_id;
    auto end = beg + n;

    return findtwoSum_impl(thread_id, beg, end);
}
```

you have the following `beg == end == data.begin()`. **At this point no thread perform any computation and exit**.

```
thread::id of a non-executing thread is joinable? 0
```

This is because the thread has already completed

```
140634635626240 is joinable? 1
```

This is when the thread is still running\runnable.

The output will always vary due to scheduling of threads being completely random. This is normal, even if you didn't have any bug in your code.

**Please note** : Set up everything before launching threads : This avoid the awkward reliance on `std::shared_future<void> is_ready;`